# In the javac command how to give custom class file name?

Tags: java, class, javac

I am compiling a java source file named MyPeogram.java. Now I want to use javac to compile the file and save the class file in the name MyCompileCode.class. Is it possible to give such custom class names to compiled files?

Please let me know how to do this. I searched online a lot but could not find anything.

Comment: For what purpose? Even if you could accomplish this, it won't work when used.

Answer (score 3):

No.  The name of the source file must match the name of the compiled file.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, I think it is not possible, because Java is compiled and interpreted both. Even though you compiled the program and changed, it's name, **the interpreter gets confused in class file name and the data in that class file**.

Correct me, If I am wrong.

Comment: This doesn't sound like an answer in which youself have much confidence.